# Finding $\vec{v}\times\hat{i},\vec{v}\times\hat{j},\vec{v}\times\hat{k}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

How do I find the following?

\begin{align}\vec{v}\times\hat{i},\\
\vec{v}\times\hat{j},\tag{1} \\
\vec{v}\times\hat{k},\end{align}

given only that
\begin{align}
\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
9 \\ 3 \\ 2
\end{bmatrix},\tag{2}
\end{align}
and since I'm not crossing this vector with another vector it seems odd...

Thanks,

Comment: What are you talking about? $\textbf{i}$, $\textbf{j}$ and $\textbf{k}$ ARE vectors. Unit vectors, to be exact. Furthermore, the cross product only makes sense with 2 vectors.

Comment: Gee, thanks for stating the obvious.

Comment: Then why did you say you're not crossing that vector with another vector? You are.

Comment: @Dylan Sorry, I was in a bad mood earlier (something like 4 hrs of homework set me off). My apologies for the rather rude remark. I may have snapped a little :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\hat i=(1,0,0),\hat j=(0,1,0),\hat k=(0,0,1)$

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

We generally take 
\begin{align*}
\hat i &= \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} &
\hat j &= \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} &
\hat k &= \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
Furthermore, for
\begin{align*}
\vec x &= \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} &
\vec y &= \begin{bmatrix} y_1\\y_2\\y_3\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
we define $\vec x\times\vec y$ by the formula
$$
\vec x\times\vec y=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{vmatrix}x_2 & x_3\\ y_2 & y_3\end{vmatrix} \\
 -\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & x_3\\ y_1 & y_3\end{vmatrix} \\
  \begin{vmatrix}x_1 & x_2\\ y_1 & y_2\end{vmatrix} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where 
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a&b\\c&d
\end{vmatrix}=ad-bc
$$
Can you put all of this together to obtain your desired equations?

Comment: Yeah I did, and this all makes total sense but the way the question was asked -- they could not be more vague.